# Why can yielding a thread solve the thread visibility problem in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, cpu, java-memory-model

Consider the following code:

```
public class Test {
    static boolean moreLoop = true;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (moreLoop) {
                // more loop
            }
            System.out.println("loop exited");
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            moreLoop = false;
        });
        t1.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000); // so we have more confidence t1 runs first
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

After running the code, the "loop exited" statement never gets printed. I understand this is because thread 2 puts the updated boolean in the cache of the CPU in which it's running, so thread 1 can not see the change if it's running in a different CPU. If we make the `moreLoop` variable volatile then "loop exited" will soon be printed.

Here's the thing. If we leave `moreLoop` non-volatile and write `Thread.currentThread().yield();` on the line after `// more loop` inside the while loop, we will see "loop exited" printed. Using `Thread.sleep` will achieve the same effect. Why is that? Does thread 1 sync with thread 2 when it is restored?

I ask this question because my company has a WebApp written in Java that never uses volatile on the shared hash maps and the code has been working for years. My guess is that because the HTTP threads are managed by tomcat, they might get scheduled out after finishing one HTTP request and before serving the next one, just like what I described in the above paragraph. Is this possibly the reason why the code works?

Edit: If we don't use either volatile or yiled/sleep, it seems thread 1 can still see the change made by thread 2 as long as the change by thread 2 is made before the while loop starts. For example, after running the following code

```
public class Test {
    static boolean moreLoop = true;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("thread 1 started");
            for (long i = 0; i < 10_000_000_000L; ++i); // takes around 3 seconds on my machine
            System.out.println("thread 1 warmup finished");
            while (moreLoop) {
                // more loop
            }
            System.out.println("loop exited");
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("thread 2 started");
            moreLoop = false;
            System.out.println("thread 2 finished");
        });
        t1.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000); // so we have more confidence t1 runs first
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

it prints the following on my machine

```
thread 1 started
thread 2 started
thread 2 finished
thread 1 warmup finished
loop exited
```

We don't have any synchronization. Well, you may argue `System.out.println` does the synchronization. But after I removed all `println` statements except "loop exited", the code could still print "loop exited". How come thread 1 could see the change made by thread 2?

Comment: I haven't messed around with lambdas that much, but I am aware they do variable capture... that is, they copy the variables into their own context and don't see changes to them.  Googling seems to imply this happens to static variables as well.

Comment: Hi @Powerlord, I don't think it has anything to do with lambdas. Please take a look at the code here: https://pastebin.com/pTQBgTWZ. It produces the same difference.

Comment: _Why_ do `yield()` and `sleep()` make the update to `moreLoop` visible? It doesn't matter. They are _allowed_ to make the change visible. They also are allowed to _not_ make the change visible. In fact, `Thread.yield()` is allowed to do absolutely nothing at all. If you want to _guarantee_ that the change will become visible, then you have to do something (e.g., make the variable `volatile` or use `synchronized` blocks) whose documentation promises to have that effect.

Comment: @SolomonSlow `yield` and `sleep` certainly did something; otherwise, it won't be so deterministic that calling `yield` or `sleep` always makes the loop exit, and the loop never exits without them.

Comment: You're missing my point, which is that `Thread.yield()` and `Thread.sleep(n)` are not _intended_ or _required_ to have any effect on memory visibility. They had an effect in _your_ program, under _your_ JRE version, running on _your_ OS version, on _your_ hardware. But they are not required to have any such effect in _every_ program, on _every_ JRE version, on _every_ operating system and _every_ hardware platform. If it works for you, great. But, if you share your program with other people, it would be wrong to expect it to always work for them.

Comment: Hi @SolomonSlow, thanks for the clarification. I understand that the language specification doesn't associate memory visibility with `yield` or `sleep` and because of this, we would reason that this code is dangerous and it will not work all the time. However, whether it works all the time or not is not important to me. It worked on my machine, so there must have been something happening that made it work, and my question was all about what exactly is that thing.